# How to block telnet using iptables command

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, telnet

I am trying to block telnet on my server but I have failed to do so.
I have added following firewall rules in INPUT chain of filter table for the same.

```
INPUT CHAIN(filter table):
<some other firewall rules>
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 23 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0.2 -j DROP
```

based on [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=772149&s=cdd970f6898042bcaa777afbd482fcb9) on Ubuntu forums.
But I am seeing, I can still able to open telnet on my server.
I have also ready some links for the above problem but I am not getting any help.
Please let me know where I am wrong in adding rules.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should think in the opposite way: you should configure your server's firewall to block **all** ports **except** those of the services you run on the machine.  E.g. for a HTTP/HTTPS webserver that must be accessible via SSH, this is the relevant iptables config:

```
*filter 
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0] 
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0] 
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0] 
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
COMMIT
```

Secondly, your machine should not even have a telnet server running.  It's an unencrypted and insecure protocol; set up SSH instead.

This is just an extrapolation on my part, but I suspect you might want to block external users from using telnet to probe ports on your machine, e.g.

```
telnet yourhost 25
```

to probe if there's a SMTP server running.  If this is the case, you can't stop them -- just configure the firewall to block all incoming connections except those on the ports of services running on the server.

Comment: `telnet` is an extensible protocole. There exist encryption extensions for `telnet`.